# Compare more than two documents

Tags: javascript, diff

**EDIT:** *Mea culpa!* Committed the cardinal sin of asking for a library recommendation and was swiftly put to rights. Here's the problem: I have two or more pieces of text. For example:

a: `Here's some text.`

b: `Here's some more text.`

c: `Here's some text with the word blue.`

And want to get:

`'Here's some <var_1>text<var_2>.'`

where

var_1 document a holds `''`

var_1 document b holds `'more '`

var_1 document c holds `''`

var_2 document c holds `''`

var_2 document b holds `''`

var_2 document c holds `' with the word blue'`

This is for a Javascript-based web app heavily reliant on jQuery; however for testing I need solution that is compatible with node.js.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex like `/(.*)text(.*)/` might do it.

Then you can use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to get the values of the capturing groups.

```js
var str = ["Here's some text","Here's some more text.","Here's some text with the word blue."];

for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    var res = str[i].match(/(.*)text(.*)/);
    log("document "+i+" var_1 : "+res[1]+"<br>"+"document "+i+" var_2 : "+ res[2]+"<br>");
  }

function log(msg){
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML+= msg;
  }
```

```html
<p/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to know the input documents all have `text` in common?

Comment: Yes of course, and you'll have to replace `text` in `/(.*)text(.*)/);`by the one in common. But Do you mean you don't know this common part yet?